# GitLab runner cannot write file

Tags: docker, shell, gitlab, alpine-linux

As shown below, I tried to write my public key into `/root/.ssh/known_hosts` in some a shared GitLab runner with the executor of docker using the alpine docker image.

Variable `$HOST_FINGERPRINT` is initialized which could be proven by the command `echo $HOST_FINGERPRINT`, but it just cannot be output to the known_hosts file for some reason.

Does anybody have any clue?

```sh
$ ls -al
total 32
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root          4096 Jul 11 00:15 .
drwxrwxrwx    8 root     root          4096 Jul 11 00:15 ..
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           121 Jul 11 00:15 Dockerfile
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           183 Jul 11 00:15 known_hosts
$ echo $HOST_FINGERFRINT
xxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxx, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBAG/dWuic73JmrfWPxJkKlW2xXFUJUGkoF2XnPZeVMUE+LF4VU9QXnukuTXFiKCZQGqrnK8UquqSRc3Z/MTBBdo=
$ echo $HOST_FINGERPRINT > known_hosts
$ echo $?
0
$ ls -l .
total 16
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           121 Jul 11 00:15 Dockerfile
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             1 Jul 11 00:15 known_hosts
$ echo $HOST_FINGERPRINT > known
$ echo $?
0
$ ls -l .
total 24
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           121 Jul 11 00:15 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             1 Jul 11 00:15 known
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             1 Jul 11 00:15 known_hosts
```

Comment: Is maybe somebody else writing to that file at the same time? Try a `lsof | grep known_hosts`

Comment: Good Guess, but it won't happen. It is a gitlab runner(container in essence) created whenever you run it, instead of a regular OS where it is possible that multiple users are logged in at some a time. As a result, I cannot create a TTY at that time and see what happened there. I can only provide those commands in form of scripts, while I can not decide how they are executed.